# Zip code based on a array with errors

Tags: php, zipcode

I want to develop a zip code finder, the zip code consists of 4 digits and two letters. If the zip code is correct, the user will receive a confirmation that we deliver in that district. If not, a message that we don't deliver there.

And if the zip code doesn't contain the correct criteria an error with: enter the correct zip code 4 digits and 2 letters.

Here's a rough mockup of the php:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
{
    $postcode = array(6458,7493,6002,7520); 
    if(in_array($_POST['postcode'],$postcode))
    {
            echo 'We deliver on that district';
    }
    else
    {
        echo  'This order can not be delivered in that area';
    }
}


function IsPostcode($value) {
return preg_match('/^[1-9][0-9]{3} ?[a-zA-Z]{2}$/', $value);
}

if(IsPostcode($_POST['postcode'])) {
    echo 'Correct Zip code';
}
else {
    echo 'Incorrect zip code enter 4 letters and 2 numbers';
}

?>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">
<input type="text" name="postcode" />
<input type="submit" value="verstuur" />
</form>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: is it always in the format Digit, Digit, Digit, Letter, Letter?

Comment: the question is how can I show a error message when the user doesn't fill a zip code with digit, digit, digit, digit, letter, letter?

if the user doesn't fill the correct criteria (4 digits 2 letters) I want to show a error message.

Comment: But you already are doing that, the regex looks fine, and you have logic that checks the post code is fine and then outputs the message, you will have to be more specific

Comment: A example; when I fill 3 digits only; the error message shows this: "This order can not be delivered in that area. Incorrect zip code enter 4 letters and 2 numbers" 

I want to show only the second error message: "Incorrect zip code enter 4 letters and 2 numbers"

Comment: You just need to restructure your conditionals in that case.

Comment: @chris85 can you give me a example? I'm new with php and struggle a lot of time with this problem :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
    $postcode = array(6458,7493,6002,7520);
    if(preg_match('/^[1-9][0-9]{3} ?[a-zA-Z]{2}$/', $_POST['postcode'])) {
        if(in_array($_POST['postcode'],$postcode)) {
            echo 'We deliver on that district';
        } else {
            echo  'This order can not be delivered in that area';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Incorrect zip code enter 4 letters and 2 numbers';
    }
}
?>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">
    <input type="text" name="postcode" />
    <input type="submit" value="verstuur" />
</form>
```

It should first check if it meets your regex and if it does then check if they are inside of a range you've allowed. Your regex doesn't match the allowed addresses currently so these all will be `This order can not be delivered in that area` or `Incorrect zip code enter 4 letters and 2 numbers`.

You also don't need a function that just returns a the result of a native PHP function.